# Webscraping by python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am a new learner of python. I need to web scrape from the website "walletexplorer" (https://www.walletexplorer.com/) where I need to generate five tsv output files() from the homepage tables each needs to just scrape all the addresses linked to the wallet. The sample output could be like the following :

```
exchanges.tsv
wallet     addresses
Huobi.com    19hx1B4pTDsBAYJJYYrj1t6bcVw1e9omuH
Huobi.com    16vyeuwbuNz9PKPs4VqqGLsVRJ2G6uJj39
...      ...    
Zydo.com     15ovvTEgmQEprftNH1yAgkZ5uHY1YqAnvu
```

The code I attempted is just the following, I can't figure out how to proceed after this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_upcoming_events(url):
    req = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

    events = soup.find({'class': 'serviceslist'}).findAll('href')
get_upcoming_events('https://www.walletexplorer.com/')
```

Grateful if someone can guide me with a few explanations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not even getting the pages with the wallet addresses. All you have are links to services. You'd have visit every service link, loop thru all the transaction pages, scrape the addresses and move on to the next service.

Comment: @baduker Thanks, but each wallet has list of addresses pages. No need to go to transaction page. can you explain it with some sample code? How can I do it for multiple pages of address table?

Comment: Well, there's *a lot* of those addresses, some services have millions of them. Do you really need that data? If so, scraping it will get you throttled and/or blocked. However, you can either compute the address yourself or ask for access to the API. Check this - https://www.walletexplorer.com/info

Comment: @baduker Thank you. I am requesting a API access.  But, just to my learning purpose If I need only the last column of old/historic wallets to address tsv file how can I do that? If you can just explain by some sample codes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source_url = "https://www.walletexplorer.com/"

services = [
    f'{source_url}wallet/{s["href"].rsplit("/")[-1]}/addresses' for s
    in BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(source_url).text,
        "html.parser",
    ).select("table.serviceslist td ul li a")
]

for service in services[:1]:
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(service).text, "html.parser")
    print(f"Wallet addresses for {service.rsplit('/')[-2]}")
    print([i.find("a").getText() for i in s.find_all("td") if i.find("a")])
```

Which outputs:

```
Wallet addresses for Huobi.com
['19hx1B4pTDsBAYJJYYrj1t6bcVw1e9omuH', '16vyeuwbuNz9PKPs4VqqGLsVRJ2G6uJj39', '12uuCfvuxeyGhWaEU1sHTbkCN7eWMT7qFp', '1NMbcRqggWu75DG5AqZtin5kecdHoDVs3b', '1DgcQFeaCQBo41oxtzUuV3caW5TNjXvhLZ', '16K4VtKNxcaNkvNvDYiiWjyn1n49irJ8Ep', '1FDpmBztMAUvR1Q4JJeb2FnA4VUxUAAtmd', '1ko9cGfFxWoUMMZ3MsxuSjRHfLDNgyjr9', '1MnkzcBw8prYASnMiJ772ApcEsn1tFtn1A', '1CXrs7piiUdDXG1nT8jk43GWqCtPpbQbYu', '17WQqNZafGZWWa1zW4LaJ1h7S7qKKER8as', '14zzx8PWeXULMp11NmFdk3yuTabME6naBN', '1H8casG2e6keyjVGoQeh21oE2UJCtXECSL', '1JHsjazLvtpW6MC3AppTK8FtDU79mKeJDg', '18FVW8RUVnoHwBGFkRFsf9kyAHJcrcbiuS', '1F3GeJi6VesFMkaUF9o81vtJFkTdCs59bC', '1NMwkFzhkPRdK1XCH8dKxWmsCDCFFmx8Rq', '1BzudAAfaaqtNVUs1ZjFAzSZKoWKSg6NYY', '1LvWcQMQS8X5uyX7sSZSkEaUeM1ojYZ6r3', '1KXiM8NMPfAHvRdt3ZvUDrFWW1B29i2xr6', '1MTKTCg7Xh3yinQ87sjUzp73ES5caET61t', '15s6yYhzVsrM29nBi1geaJuBZFGQtMdhA6', '12aKRDdkL5Ae3zRVwbs9ywPo4Jfx44GYfd', '185ohog3RpD81YnG1p3Eb4DaS4FtU4hHc7', '1Crucw3RmmFvNdM35mt5QKC4tbVwWgXDgd', '1vdXJDiDSzeUAoM7eAcWZPhM9wEKmH8dG', '1HcQVoEFKk9rqU61UnAsKczxkeEj31hE92', '1Eb3pnx8LKsu4m7fR6Bt2bBw7wcEiH2erW', '1BDvRoPJK2evVhRRWJg3Fhyv7WPpwuiubJ', '144jMnE7sagf67e2e1vX9YPX9BhvWSoMnD', '12pjLweEBXtToCmqxQvimaEf3gxuHaCrhb', '12AH4fFy4FXYRzDhkYTtWdq3rFqFa6TJ4U', '1MwvFVwzZHSAsvvFSkdfU2EA5ieJC7YAWH', '17o41kDRLPvUGeQyu7gfymC3eRPTg6434v', '15N2pWryiFtFAyQC5c9vHTXimutSTFjDb5', '13L37EaqqSjXva9DcSgNQDWPV7Urko2wkZ', '1FAh5udQQvKxKuDARKB5qV26LcijqA7dy1', '16aJR7AYANSeJvqYgBEcd46rBQTasqs1ve', '1MRpBNxmFWB1xAwxmohFuRUL8whCsf2DBh', '1Q8Ho6YQzUmm8KKqYAgzfFGMqb6K83sxsN', '1HBnzQb6Vajf9yh2jiFkmvyfYZfFq9Ynyy', '1DWnomNDC6NRJDyrvqbLEEpXzpQRyap6jA', '1FkxMFkpsMDXtk2kCgViuLKJCyj55ZgL9v', '12o3YqvQ3u7phFd4YDitJ18BncGDTdFwtn', '1BT8GW75RwbKFeYXywqXfFB7fnd9BX6eKr', '13o5epgXwGyTZWSJMww18bry5AyQkUEMpu', '1GbiA1PKiHW8xNi9g71pMtFKsSs4ZAa8bQ', '1H66qMnVyW198rX576mHoierUJPhsxC6UA', '1AZifFwpYxJ6VGFuPzE1zSHD33FxNWCSXS', '1EA2ZCZEfxv7rW3mifz9jSK2yWeS3akRpc', '1LgCndYGW7rvUCjXPaxM7F7SnJCPA3aUjj', '1awTScPNF8zF5xieKCnVq2MoVkJms6sAf', '1QCph5a9Fm9e1p48iKnfmdEdZfPEAL6WWi', '13ND5KqL8FMK11udMNzfHBkqhJS4p1Vtw6', '1PMmHeQJB6VogEja98Un1h89WPvyKSKj19', '18efnKBBZqKqY6q1U3bVe1NB3HNxhsK686', '1PgPrjtVFvDC4vNwzoLhQsM5XSNHRBjQim', '1JAVtXrWbNmtat8ngVDCkV77HCtJapqxz8', '181zaA5V8ntBqjBFPEwTrZWBFyme7av9uD', '1GDLvz5gY4KR2J562gorQNhZUdfR1XVZES', '18iBEue7bK74axy4WMj8Yc5iPZZNj9sZ9B', '12k1wjjxz2t6KVmiYSxHXjoN3naE1FTwZq', '1HJV7cZ8TtbeCVfTVQP9TA16sgWJ1Qfarr', '1xXUeCGYzyGcwPa6V4pbi7gv1MDUc7Q7f', '1NHgveRqK326LeievoSrAGnknfMci9hLgs', '18CDxW6kKu5EmxwokmFe2njipVZpow88qX', '1DhWzMdZWwZXwmCYEajf4Auj3euaYtkFVJ', '1EWdvNgW1YTshfoM25E9LRmtktqFgJRoAN', '1CSydWPpafwEkYVZTbEas4bBAUEfVJ8SUp', '1ELbdBEn4zcvwCoWDPmmA31FRzsDo4mnSm', '1MXQSdXNR8P8bCT6732t8yu9fYAPTQUuxr', '1MNoBZr1GaDrxpNGxQmBhjJf6ycZdgU56X', '15bpXYz5FnTmh7cQQpUV7HiAGzHyvNxvex', '14hSMo1zBP4JE5r8soe3mmbhowrXdjHT8J', '1Csim7JNUrRgQ53W8GLK5Q2LYWxDEAhywR', '1AfypffpYUUzcaKU8XRvx6bfZsqr3sYdjP', '1M62FoKigWRCCVaXyNVhNBiH94WQFswLQW', '183xR5W1Vqw6gSKdteH5h9haWct23XGXa4', '1LYZkpA9jDHVCXrmzKwmKutNFk58JHj6rJ', '1ACeg9dJM4ogXGPyxYLHzvTj6AgM9S1d4u', '12Nv7TsECtLrWvdZjsd2M1vEJ5V8kLRQXP', '1NmC4QEjbjsCGgbDntJgdJEgXRx1yq8uqb', '1H7j2YeKwdatfmTmE6vUMotMNrnLA1JbyS', '1LWpXdrYKstHqLt1djAms1MRGhatn2YFcq', '1DWC7StAcFD8ydTvcHdxRx7GDQ7BBVqX7h', '1HS2BryuSnU4BAQLemfosBnZP7C7vom456', '1JBCzSCHgZWidMRHUqk2N7EVoPo4sNkER1', '168YVdM3qQtHURwzkJVVpt9ArLk5HtzWp8', '12ZMUTSQC3agsXWpPzyrBCkRGe7cRy2o32', '1JiyES25B4WLDsrvajHmM6PWrFjEk9vCmS', '1GhSk27WnVkhuNzPCT3SNMcSh4zowjqNcH', '1L5XCihBQrXuhR1T9oiyxXutKw3oS1i2eW', '1BgVEbXkKfPmy5zPgEQRpoDZtrZzRghn97', '19j3XsGnq8T9JtoGQuzqr5PX1d5ZWrWLFq', '1FqFJHvR91t8DTjAVD75CJ4cKTxuPPu6Cq', '169tgLDYcs68f3ZYh35k8JV5oyBZm5xLFa', '1J4Hi1emZUkTBgSJHHZfN56EAyzzVXqCEv', '1851LgKaSxjCHmmmEKXhoN8d3SNr4xU1LR', '1EcUMEdqMJkcpnwRxjaXf1a6dBCbDFqHGH', '18G2iXLSvCnFEvTmHMmu5SFVg3jnvdKtMX']
```